# How to apply plugin in gradle conditional dependent on OS

Tags: windows, gradle

I have added a plugin **id "ua.eshepelyuk.ManifestClasspath" version "1.0.0"**  to plugins {} in my build.gradle file. I **would like to only run the plugin when using a windows computer.
So what I tried is to add an if statement around the plugin. I have included Gradle plugin with my if statement below:

Build.graddle file:

```
plugins {
   if (System.getProperty("os.name").toLowerCase().contains("windows")) {
    id "ua.eshepelyuk.ManifestClasspath" version "1.0.0"
  }
}
```

When using the if statement above I get the error: 'only id(String) method calls allowed in plugins {} script block'. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Give below a try...

```
plugins {
    id "ua.eshepelyuk.ManifestClasspath" version "1.0.0" apply false
}

if(System.getProperty("os.name").toLowerCase().contains("windows")) {
    apply plugin: “ua.eshepelyuk.ManifestClasspath”
}
```